# ASP.NET - Maintaining a unsaved model state across multiple pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to create a set of views to gather a lot of information.  I say set because I have broken up this information across several pages, organized by the type of questions.  I want the user to be able to leave and add, remove, update data as they wish, but I also need them to be able to cancel their changes.  Seems simple enough.

But conceptualizing this from a code point of view, I'm having issues.

At first I wanted to preserve the model across multiple pages.  So I would have a controller that redirects to different views depending on the step they have and pass the model around until they saved.  However, unless I store all the information they aren't currently working on in hidden fields, the model I return from the view to go to the next step is half empty.

I then considered working with session variables.  I then figured that if I pressed the back button or left the "workflow" without clicking cancel to clear the session variable, then I risk a user reopening the same object and their changes still be there.

I don't really see an elegant way of doing this.  I assume this is my lack of ASP.NET\MVC experience.

Comment: This sounds like a perfect candidate for session usage.  You could set the session length to a lower time if you're concerned about the data staying alive too long.

Comment: We had similar project. We saved data in the database tables. Once user hit final submit it will go to the appropriate tables and data in the staging tables were deleted. We used sessions before. But with growing number of users we had performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

We are doing something similar where I work, where there is a wizard type of interface, and each step is its own view.  At the moment, we have enabled session to save a top-level model between steps, but this is temporary for us.  In order to avoid the overhead of session (request lifecycle-wise and network traffic for the state server), we will likely soon switch to persisting the top-level model as JSON to a database table (along with a key to the user), and in the future, we may build out strongly-typed storage tables for the data in the model, for easier querying/reporting on users in-process.  This also allows us to control the lifetime of the data, and the user may continue where they left off the next time they login.  MVC purists seem to say to not use ASP.net session state, but I'm not exactly sure why.  It may be because by using session, you are no longer being REST-ful, but MVC != REST (although it can).  I would say that if you are short on time, enabling session state and just throwing the data there could enable you to get it done faster.  You can always change it out later like my team plans on doing.  The real answer here depends on your business requirements as well.  Anyway, hopefully this adds something useful to the question.